# Array post with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I found many posts about that, but nothing for me :(

I'm using Jquery-Plugin [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) and I have many tables in a form (But i don't know how many).

I should get the formdata from the plugin with:

```
objDataTables.each(function(index){
    dtArray[$(this).attr('id')] = $('input', $(this).fnGetNodes()).serialize();
});
```

How can i send the *dtArray* to the server per `$.ajax` 
I tried to creat an Object `dtArray = {}` but it still not working. The *postdata* are an empty string every time.

Anybody have an Idea why or how?

Thanks.

*Note: I don't using `JSON.stringify(...)`*

Comment: why you don't use `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: In what structure does your server expect the data to be? Note that `.serialize()` returns a string of the form `foo=bar&baz=42`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it :)
Create an Object and not an Array. Note: Don't serialize the Object.
If anyone else have the same case... my Solution

```
var tData = {};
for(var index in dtArray){
    tData[index] = $('input', dtArray[index].fnGetNodes()).serialize();
};
```

and in Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 4000,
    data: { func: "ajax", formData: tData },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // to do
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // to do
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't you say: *" I tried to creat an Object `dtArray = {}` but it still not working."*? What is `dtArray` in your code?

Comment: Oh Yes, I did, but i tried to serlialize the Object befor sendt it per ajax. The serialization returns an empty string ^^
thx

Comment: dtArray ist an array of DataTables-Objects.
`for(var table in $('table')) { $(table).dataTable(...); }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the data you wish to send is in either an input or textarea tag? 
Other elements, such as tables, wont be collected by the serialize function.

If the data is not in input or textarea fields but you still want to collect it, then you will have to iterate through all rows and columns.